# Why does Yon-Rogg lie to Ronan about Skrulls being on Earth?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In *Captain Marvel*, after Carol Danvers is stranded on Earth, Ronan the Accuser calls Yon-Rogg via hologram. When a member of Starforce is about to report that Skrulls have infiltrated Earth, Yon-Rogg interrupts and claims they have nothing to report.

Yon-Rogg would later tell Ronan that Skrulls had invaded Earth, but only begrudgingly after Carol Danvers rescued the Skrulls and escaped with the Tesseract.

**Why didn't Yon-Rogg want Ronan to know that Skrulls had invaded Earth?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

He didn't tell Ronan about the Skrulls on Earth because he knew if he did Ronan would send his forces to try and destroy it, or part of it. This is exactly what happens at the end of the movie when he finally tells Ronan. He didn't want Ronan to destroy Earth because Vers (Carol) was still on Earth and he didn't want to lose her, or her powers, either by killing her or making her turn against the Kree.

His plan was to save Vers, kill the Skrull himself and then carry on like normal. This only changed when he realised Vers was once again Carol and had been told the truth and so was now his enemy. At that point he realised the game was up and so his objective was now to stop her as well as the Skrulls. Calling in Ronan to destroy Earth was essentially a fail safe should he have failed.

---

<sub>*This is written from memory of the film and as it is still new I unfortunately don't have any quotes to add in yet, will add some when available.*</sub>

Comment: On a completely unrelated note this was my 500th answer apparently!

Comment: congrats!  on your 500 answers :)